# JavaNullPointer Exception on ArrayList Add Function

Tags: android, arraylist

Hope you are doing well

i am facing issue while adding object to ArrayList
i need your kind assistance in solving this problem
each time when i am going to add something to selectedContacts ArrayList i got nullPointerException

```
ArrayList<ContactInfo> selectedContacts = new ArrayList<>();
    public ArrayList<ContactInfo> getSelectedContacts()
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (contacts.get(i).isCheck()==true)
            {
                ContactInfo info = contacts.get(i);
                if(info != null)
                    selectedContacts.add(info);
                i++;
            }
            return selectedContacts;
        }
```

ContactInfo.Java

```
public class ContactInfo {
    String name;
    String number;
    String email;
    boolean check;

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setCheck(boolean check) {
        this.check = check;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public boolean isCheck() {
        return check;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

}
```

Comment: Obviously contacts or contacts.get(i) is null

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since your returning `selectedContacts` in your `getSelectedContacts` method, you would be better moving the `ArrayList` declaration inside your method. Such as;

```
public ArrayList<ContactInfo> getSelectedContacts()
{
    ArrayList<ContactInfo> selectedContacts = new ArrayList<>();

    int i = 0;
    while (contacts.get(i).isCheck()==true)
    {
        ContactInfo info = contacts.get(i);
        if(info != null)
            selectedContacts.add(info);
        i++;
    }
    return selectedContacts;
}
```

Comment: Maybe...  But it will not fix npe

Comment: Provide more information then ... Are you sure contacts exist and the issue is actually with adding `info` to `selectedContacts`?

Comment: yes contacts exist and issue is only while adding them

Comment: Body of while loop doesn't matter as obviously npe is in conditions check

Comment: Something is probably resetting `selectedContacts` if you are getting a null exception when adding. ArrayLists wont be checking your `ContactInfo` and verifying anything there. So either your loop is wrong, and `contacts` doesnt exist or `selectedContacts` is being set to null in other parts of your code.

Comment: thanks @sixones by Declaring and initializing selectedContacts inside the function has solved the problem (y)

Comment: Glad to be of help!